# How to divide a XML file in two using HREF?

Tags: html, xml, html-parsing, href

I am trying to make a particular XML file that uses HTML href elements to be divided into 2 files without breaking link consistency. Here is a snippet of the file where  I want to break in two.

```
<...Lots_of_irrelevant_code_here/>     
<CreaturePowerPointsForOneEnergy>25</CreaturePowerPointsForOneEnergy>
<NecroPendant_CreatureCostDisountPercents>20</NecroPendant_CreatureCostDisountPercents>
<TransformTable>
    <Item>
        <Dead>CREATURE_ACIDIC_HYDRA</Dead>
        <Rise>CREATURE_LICH_MASTER</Rise>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Dead>CREATURE_ANGEL</Dead>
        <Rise>CREATURE_BONE_DRAGON</Rise>
    </Item>
</TransformTable>
```

I want to migrate **TransformTable** and its content to a separate file and give the link to the original file. Here is an example that does not work.

```
<...Lots_of_irrelevant_code_here/>     
<CreaturePowerPointsForOneEnergy>25</CreaturePowerPointsForOneEnergy>
<NecroPendant_CreatureCostDisountPercents>20</NecroPendant_CreatureCostDisountPercents>
<TransformTable href="TransformTable.xdb"/>
```

Where **TransformTable.xdb** is:

```
 <Item>
        <Dead>CREATURE_ACIDIC_HYDRA</Dead>
        <Rise>CREATURE_LICH_MASTER</Rise>
 </Item>
 <Item>
        <Dead>CREATURE_ANGEL</Dead>
        <Rise>CREATURE_BONE_DRAGON</Rise>
 </Item>
```

It is very important that the parser does not find a difference after the change. I tried this but it did not work as well.

main file:

```
<TransformTable href="TransformTable.xdb#xpointer(/TransformTable)"/>
```

second file:

```
<TransformTable>
    <Item>
        <Dead>CREATURE_ACIDIC_HYDRA</Dead>
        <Rise>CREATURE_LICH_MASTER</Rise>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Dead>CREATURE_ANGEL</Dead>
        <Rise>CREATURE_BONE_DRAGON</Rise>
    </Item>
</TransformTable>
```

Based on the Xinclude suggestion I tried this but yet not working.
main file:

```
<TransformTable> 
    <xi:include href="TransformTable.xdb"/> 
</TransformTable>
```

TransformTable.xdb:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<Item> 
    <Dead>CREATURE_ACIDIC_HYDRA</Dead> 
    <Rise>CREATURE_LICH_MASTER</Rise> 
</Item> 
<Item> 
    <Dead>CREATURE_ANGEL</Dead> 
    <Rise>CREATURE_BONE_DRAGON</Rise> 
</Item> 
... and more items it that manner.
```

Comment: [XInclude](https://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/)?

Comment: Thank you but the parser that reads the file is a binary made in 2006 which I cannot modify. From what I see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302291.aspx#xinc_topic4 , Xinclude is not native to xml :(.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: @JordanKostov: And `href` is native to XML?

Comment: haha, not but I see that the parser uses it.
@BillBell I updated the main topic with what I tried.

Comment: Basically I try to do whatever the parser allows me by reverse engineering it.